# Cannot write .csv file to StringGrid in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, csv

EDIT: Codeblock edited,  now only problem is only last line of .csv file is printed in each row of StringGrid. What can be the reason? Thanks in advance.

Basically , one module of project does create an output file with toushands of point coordinates in comma seperated format like shown below :

```
#pt,     x     ,     y     ,z    
124,4500003.833,3499999.500,0
125,4500003.833,3499999.833,0
126,4500003.833,3500000.167,0
```

What i'm trying to do is reading the .csv with another module and put it into a StringGrid.

```
 FILE *coord;

 //some other things here

while (fgets(line,100,DosyaGiris)!=NULL) {

 sscanf(line,"%d,%lf,%lf,%lf",&number,&x,&y,&z);
        for (col = 0; col < 4; col++) {

                StringGrid1->Cells[0][row] = IntToStr(number);
                StringGrid1->Cells[1][row] = FloatToStr(x);
                StringGrid1->Cells[2][row] = FloatToStr(y);
                StringGrid1->Cells[3][row] = FloatToStr(z);

        }

}
```

Please be constructive , have a good one.

Comment: What exactly is central problem? Do You try debugging?

Comment: Offtopic : you are using c++, so use c++ library, instead of old C one => `FILE *` and associated functions => replaced by `ifstream`; `sscanf` => `stringstream`; `fgets` => `std::getline`; `char *` or `char[]`=> `std::string`

Comment: @Garf365 yeah i'm aware of that , thanks mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not working because of that unnecessary for loop, now it works.

```
        int i= 0;
        while (fgets(line,100,DosyaGiris)!=NULL){
            sscanf(line,"%d,%lf,%lf,%lf",&ID,&x,&y,&z);

                StringGrid1->Cells[0][i+1] = IntToStr(ID);
                StringGrid1->Cells[1][i+1] = FloatToStr(x);
                StringGrid1->Cells[2][i+1] = FloatToStr(y);
                StringGrid1->Cells[3][i+1] = FloatToStr(z);
                i++;

        }
```